# How to capture click with ListView in UWP?

Tags: c#, listview, mvvm, uwp, viewmodel

I would like to capture click events from listview through my viewmodel. Here's what I have so far.

My Xaml.

```
        <ListView RelativePanel.Below="list3" ItemClick="{x:Bind ViewModel.ClickItemList}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
            <ListViewHeaderItem Content="Header"></ListViewHeaderItem>
            <ListViewItem Content="Item 1" />
            <ListViewItem Content="Item 2" />
        </ListView>
```

My ViewModel.

```
    public void ClickItemList(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
    {
        var clickedItem = (ListViewItem)e.ClickedItem;

        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(clickedItem.Content);
    }
```

Unfortunately, ClickItemList is not triggered.

What is the recommended way to capture click in ListViewItem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should set the `IsItemClickEnabled="True"`

```
   <ListView RelativePanel.Below="list3" IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="{x:Bind ViewModel.ClickItemList}" RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True" RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
            <ListViewHeaderItem Content="Header"></ListViewHeaderItem>
            <ListViewItem Content="Item 1" />
            <ListViewItem Content="Item 2" />
        </ListView>
```

Comment: *smacks my head*

Answer (score 3):

You need `IsItemClickEnabled`:

```
<ListView RelativePanel.Below="list3"
          IsItemClickEnabled="True"
          ItemClick="{x:Bind ViewModel.ClickItemList}"
          RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
          RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True">
    <ListViewHeaderItem Content="Header"></ListViewHeaderItem>
    <ListViewItem Content="Item 1" />
    <ListViewItem Content="Item 2" />
</ListView>
```